# Server Response Time is Much Longer Than Expected

Tags: python, html, django, web, loading

I have an Django application which runs on my localhost currently. Some of the pages take much longer time, so for debugging reasons I calculated the time spend in one of the class based views with this simple code:

```
class DiscoverView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = "app1/discover.html"
    context_object_name = 'influencers'  # not necessary, default is object_list

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        start_time = time.time()
        # ...
        # Some tasks which I tought they are the reasons of long response time
        # ...
        print(time.time() - start_time, "seconds took to complete...")
        return context
```

After the experiments I saw that this view takes **0.01 seconds** to complete, while the page is loading in nearly ~5 seconds.

For further debugging I dig into Chrome Dev Toools. There in network tab 'Finish' time of the page is 5.86 seconds. I also runned Lighthouse test, which says that servers initial response time is ~2 seconds.

I can't understand why this 0.01 seconds becomes 2 seconds, I also used django-debug-toolbar in order to inspect database query times, which are not that long. My application is also living on production (Heroku), the loading times are much worse there of course but I feel like I need to fix that problem locally first.

I appreciate any kinds of help or debugging suggestions, please tell me If you need more information about the app/system.

**EDIT:** Here is inside of `get_context_data()` :

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        platform = self.kwargs['platform']
        page_no = self.request.GET.get('page') # make it int to multiply when slicing
        if page_no is not None: page_no = int(page_no)
        ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 10
        parents = None
        
        if platform == 'instagram':
            # Will implement this later
            pass
        elif platform == 'tiktok':
            tiktok_influencers = TiktokInfluencer.objects.all()
            context['platform_counter'] = tiktok_influencers.count()
            parents = InfluencerParent.objects.filter(tiktok__id__in = tiktok_influencers)
        elif platform == 'youtube':
            youtube_influencers = YoutubeInfluencer.objects.all()
            context['platform_counter'] = youtube_influencers.count()
            parents = InfluencerParent.objects.filter(youtube__id__in = youtube_influencers)
        elif platform == 'twitch':
            twitch_influencers = TwitchInfluencer.objects.all()
            context['platform_counter'] = twitch_influencers.count()
            parents = InfluencerParent.objects.filter(twitch__id__in = twitch_influencers)
        elif platform == 'clubhouse':
            clubhouse_influencers = ClubhouseInfluencer.objects.all()
            context['platform_counter'] = clubhouse_influencers.count()
            parents = InfluencerParent.objects.filter(clubhouse__id__in = clubhouse_influencers)
        else:
            # unknown platform, redirect to 404
            pass
        
        # Pagination stuff
        if page_no == None or page_no == 1:
            parents = parents[:ITEMS_PER_PAGE]
        else:
            parents = parents[(page_no-1) * ITEMS_PER_PAGE : (page_no) * ITEMS_PER_PAGE]

        context['influencers'] = parents
        context['platform'] = platform

        print(time.time() - start_time, "seconds took DiscoverView to complete...")
        return context
```

**EDIT 2:** I need further help so I'm adding model and template info:

```
# models.py
class InfluencerParent(models.Model):
'''
Parent class which points to influencers' IG, YT & other social media platform accounts
'''
    
def __str__(self):
    if self.instagram.first():
        return self.instagram.first().fullname
    else:
        return "None"

class InstagramInfluencer(models.Model):
    # some fields...
    influencer_parent = models.ForeignKey(InfluencerParent, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='instagram', default=None, blank=True, null=True)

class YoutubeInfluencer(models.Model):
    # some fields...
    influencer_parent = models.ForeignKey(InfluencerParent, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='instagram', default=None, blank=True, null=True)

class TiktokInfluencer(models.Model):
    # some fields...
    influencer_parent = models.ForeignKey(InfluencerParent, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='instagram', default=None, blank=True, null=True)

class TwitchInfluencer(models.Model):
    # some fields...
    influencer_parent = models.ForeignKey(InfluencerParent, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='instagram', default=None, blank=True, null=True)

class ClubhouseInfluencer(models.Model):
    # some fields...
    influencer_parent = models.ForeignKey(InfluencerParent, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='instagram', default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

**TEMPLATE SAMPLE:**

```
# template (not the all for the sake of clarity)
<!-- discover.html

A single template to list all influencers (IG, YT, Tiktok...)
Takes platform param from URL
In view we filtered parents according to the platform
For example if platform param is 'tiktok' I use this updated version:   
parents = InfluencerParent.objects.filter(tiktok__isnull=False).prefetch_related('instagram', 'youtube', 'tiktok', 'twitch', 'clubhouse')

There parents influencers are who have tiktok accounts, in template I show all the social media cards in a tabbed design
So I need to send parent and acces parent.instagram.first.username
-->

{% for influencer in influencers %}

<div class="instagram" {% influencer.instagram.first == None %} disabled {% endif %}>
    {{influencer.instagram.first.username}}
</div>

<div class="tiktok" {% influencer.tiktok.first == None %} disabled {% endif %}>
    {{influencer.tiktok.first.username}}
</div>

<!-- 
. 
. 
OTHER SOCIAL MEDDIA ACCOUNTS OF THAT PARENT
. 
. 
-->

<div class="clubhouse" {% influencer.clubhouse.first == None %} disabled {% endif %}>
    {{influencer.clubhouse.first.username}}
</div>
```

Here is how I use prefetch_related (select_related gives error):

```
elif platform == 'tiktok':
    context['platform_counter'] = TiktokInfluencer.objects.count()
    parents = InfluencerParent.objects.filter(tiktok__isnull=False).prefetch_related('instagram', 'youtube', 'tiktok', 'twitch', 'clubhouse')
    # This is how I use prefetch_lated(), I need to send parent objecjts and their all (if exists) platform related influencer objects
    # I acces Parent's all existing reverse foreign key fields in one template, for example:
    # {{parent.influencer.username}}
    # {{parent.youtube.follower_count}}
    # {{parent.tiktok.fullname}}
    # ...

    # The row below gives error: 'Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'tiktok'. Choices are: (none)'
    # Even tho I need  to give all social platforms as params (select_related('instagram', 'youtube', 'tiktok', 'twitch', 'clubhouse'))
    parents = InfluencerParent.objects.select_related('tiktok')
```

Comment: You should install Django Debug Toolbar, this will help with debugging some load times: https://pypi.org/project/django-debug-toolbar/

Comment: Can you add any template or view code which is accessing anything from your models? Its likely you have a for loop which is hitting the database in each iteration.

Comment: Timing `get_context_data` is not a great way of measuring time... For instance querysets are lazy and hence most likely expensive queries won't be noticed by timing that, instead most of the time would be taken while rendering the template where you loop over the queryset (for example your problem might be N + 1 queries, etc.). Another possible issue would be that this might be a request after quite some time, hence Django needs to make a new connection with the database because there is no old connection to reuse which again might take some time.

Comment: I already installed and inspected with django-debug-toolbar and indeed it takes crazy amount of time when I enable 'SQL' (1355 queries in 973ms). I edited my post and added inside of get_context_data() but I can't add my template here which is 1300 lines long, is there way that I can share it properly here (by uploading somewhere and giving a link maybe?)

Comment: This is going to greatly benefit you by learning Prefetch and .prefecth_related(). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/
 What you want to do is start with the first duplicate query issue. Throw in a select or prefetch_related call, and your query count will rapidly decrease as you optimize your DB hits. Without seeing your models and a few of the duplicate queires, I cannot provide anymore help. But it seems you can actually remove your .all() calls and run a Q type query to get what your looking for

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/
To help build a foundation **select_related** is for models with ForeignKey relations, and typically **prefetch_related** is for models with M2M.
Here I will provide one "simple" way to implement **prefetch_related**. Keep in mind the call to connect to the database is not just in `views.py` but also inside of your templates, accessing attributes could be an extra hit to the DB (see above link for further explanation ie. blog.author.hometown). So to alleviate how many times we access the DB, I recommend implementing something like this. Now without seeing the models, templates, and actual SQL queries this would be my best guess.

```py
        
        ...
        if platform == 'instagram':
            # Will implement this later
            pass
        elif platform == 'tiktok':
            context['platform_counter'] = TiktokInfluencer.objects.count()
            parents = InfluencerParent.objects.prefetch_related('tiktok')
        elif platform == 'youtube':
            context['platform_counter'] = YoutubeInfluencer.objects.count()
            parents = InfluencerParent.objects.prefetch_related('youtube')

         ... repeat this pattern for others
        else:
```

I think just adding the edits I made will change that query amount drastically.

If you want to see how it will change. Take a portion of your view, and do some testing in the shell

```
from django.db import reset_queries
from django.db import connection

>>> parents = list(InfluencerParent.objects.prefetch_related('tiktok'))
>>> connection.queries
>>> reset_queries()
>>> parents = list(InfluencerParent.objects.select_related('tiktok')) 
>>> connections.queries
# If both work, then your using a Forgeign Key but more importantly
# notice how many SQL queries are made. If using select_related breaks 
# its because your using an M2M. But again, the importants is getting that list of "connections" as low as possible
```

Now to further refine your code I would take a look at **Prefetch** becuase you can make *cached queries* similar to what you were implementing before.

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch

>>> qs = MyModel.objects.filter(some_lookup)
>>> results = MyDesiredResultObjects.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('some_attr'), queryset=qs, to_attr='my_new_result')
>>> my_new_result
```

===========================
Since you have provided the models
**select_related**

```py
...
elif platform == 'tiktok':
            context['platform_counter'] = TiktokInfluencer.objects.count()
            parents = InfluencerParent.objects.select_related('tiktok')
```

Comment: I never tought about how templates can make queries to database, it's a enlightment for me at the moment.  I'm using foreign key relationship, but I will try both of these 'prefetch' & 'related' and see which one has less queries. I'm going to compare the result from django-debug-toolbar and share the results here. Got a lot to read, thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. I know the last part seems cryptic, but once you read it, it will make much more sense. Post your models in the question and I may be able to help. If you find this answer helps you out, please dont foget to accept it.

Comment: I added 'prefetch_related()' and query count went from 1397 to 1317, still not sure where the bottleneck is, added more information about my models and template usage. I looked at 'Prefetch' but not sure how to use it for prefetching all social medias of parent object (backwards foreign-key), even if I can there are still nearly a thousand queries which I don't where they come from, will spend time with debug-toolbar.

Comment: Well it’s a start! Lol. Look at what SQL quieres are being duplicated. We can help if you provide some database transaction information from the debug toolbar.

Comment: Can you also post how you have implemented prefetch? Please see my answer, since now I have seen how your using the Foreign Key.

Comment: I found out that template code includes many many of usages like 'influencer.instagram.first.fieldname', '.first' makes call to the db obviously. I tryed to change that to 'influencer.instagram.all.0.fieldname' but it's still making queries to db..

Comment: You need to use select_related before accessing attrbiutes in the template? Did you try my edit?

Comment: Using select_related() gives error: 'Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'tiktok'. Choices are: (none)', I managed to get query count to 70, the problem was that I was using '.first' tag in template in so many places (180 times), which doesn't use cached queryset and makes extra queries to db, thank you for your help

Comment: Oh I see why select_related didn’t work. It’s not actually on the class. It appears that your using a parent class when you might actually  benefit by  converting to an abstract class if the child tables share the same attribute.